# To feign followed by a "that" clause

Tags: verbs

Can "feign" be followed by a "that" clause? Do these sounds natural?

> He feigned that he had gone home at the appointed time.
>
> Jessica feigned the fact that she had not done her homework.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, I think it sounds correct.

Also, Merriam-Webster uses "feigned that..." in an example sentence, as quoted below:

> [He feigned that he was not feeling well so that he could leave the party early.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feign)

Comment: Hm, I guess I won't argue with Webster. I will say, though, that following it with a noun or gerund feels more natural ("He feigned illness," "He feigned feeling unwell").

Comment: M-W is often out-of-line with other dictionaries. I don't think "feign" takes a declarative content clause as complement.

Comment: @BillJ what is the best resource on English Language usage?

Comment: I rarely use user guides, so I can't recommend one. I can recommend a good grammar book, if you're interested -- let me know.